# Best practice: reuse components or write duplicates

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a shop administration with react, alt and immutable. 
My offer object looks more or less like this:

```
offer: {
  groups: [{
     articles: [{
        optionGroups: [{
           options: []
        }]
     }]
  }]  
}
```

I iterate over every entry and display a form to edit the group, article, ... . If something is changed I call an OfferAction and pass the path, changed field and new value to the entity e.g. 
`OfferActions.update([2, 'articles', 5, 'optionGroups'], 'name', 'MyOptionGroup')`

Now I want to display the exact same form, but with different placeholders and changeHandlers. If a form is filled, the entity should be created (a different OfferAction must be called). What is best practice to do this?

I thought about the following possibilities:

**Push empty Elements on OfferStore state**
The empty elements will be displayed like the others. I don't need to duplicate any components, but I need to implement multiple checks, which OfferAction must be called after a change, placeholders to render and values to hide if they are missing. After the entity is created, I would just push another empty element onto the offer array.

**Create 2nd component**
I could just create a second component that I render. I would manage the form via an internal state, create the entity when the form is filled and reset the state. This would lead to a loot of duplicate jsx.

Is there any best practice to archieve this, without duplicating component or complicating other ones?

Comment: Create empty offer object before render,the component always related to the store.Just add a flag to offer object,eg 'isnew'.When offer with isnew==true cancelled,remove it from the store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you just want different placeholders and changeHandlers?

Set a boolean prop on the top level component that needs to be duplicated.  Then, for each placeholder/changeHandler;

```
if(this.props.someBooleanValue){
    //alternate action or placeholder
} else {
    //original action or placeholder
}
```

Include `someBooleanValue={true}` on the alternate versions, leave the originals as-is.

Comment: And how do I manage the values of my form? After the text, in an input, changed I dispatch an OfferAction.update. The offer state that is managed by my alt store gets updated and by that my props get updated as well. 
If I just change the placeholders and handlers, how can I manage the values of my form? Props are read-only and if I implement an internal state my component gets way to complicated and crammed.

Comment: I'm not clear on what form values you are trying to manage.  Aren't you just trying to push those values upwards to your Container/ActionCreator?  In any case, if your question is "how do I update these props", then the answer is "From the parent component".  When you send off the OfferAction, update your Alt Store to reference the size of your offerArray (or whatever else you're changing) that would allow the child components to dictate what they should render and what props they should pass.

Answer (score 0):

Because there are only small differences, I'd recommend you your first possibility, so create one renderer for both cases.

Add to each field the corresponding JSON object (for groups, articles e.t.c) including a field for empty elements and set it to true, e.g. isNew = true.
If you do it like this, you could use the same changehandler for all elements.

The necessary infos for the update are in the JSON object and if you have to create a new element just check the isNew flag. After adding it, set the flag to false and you can handle it like one of the existing ones.